# Building a docker image for an old version of R to utilize an older package

Tags: r, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, bioconductor

I am trying to build a docker image with R 2.5.0 (I know this is very old), and the package affyPara (also very old).  affyPara should be supported with Bioconductor version 2.7, which should run on Ubuntu 16.04.  Thus, I have been working on this dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ENV TZ UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime \
    && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone \
    && sed -Ei 's/^# deb-src /deb-src /' /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get build-dep r-base-dev -y \
    && apt-get install wget locales -y

RUN echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen en_US.utf8 \
    && /usr/sbin/update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8

ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8

RUN wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-2/R-2.5.0.tar.gz \
    && tar -xf R-2.5.0.tar.gz \
    && cd R-2.5.0 \
    && ./configure --without-x ; make \
    && make install

# Install Bioconductor version 2.7
RUN R -e 'install.packages("BiocManager", repos="https://cran.r-project.org")'
RUN R -e 'BiocManager::install(version = "2.7")'

# Install affyPara from Bioconductor version 2.7
RUN R -e 'BiocManager::install("affyPara", version = "2.7")'

CMD ["R"]
```

When I try to build this image (in the docker file's directory) with:

```
sudo docker buildx build -t affypara -f affyPara.dockerfile .
```

I get this error:

```
[+] Building 61.1s (5/10)                                                                                                                                                                                                    docker:default
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from affyPara.dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.01kB                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:16.04                                                                                                                                                                        0.4s
 => CACHED [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:16.04@sha256:1f1a2d56de1d604801a9671f301190704c25d604a416f59e03c04f5c6ffee0d6                                                                                                           0.0s
 => ERROR [2/7] RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime     && echo UTC > /etc/timezone     && sed -Ei 's/^# deb-src /deb-src /' /etc/apt/sources.list     && apt-get update -qq     && apt-get build-dep r-base-dev -y    60.5s
------
 > [2/7] RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime     && echo UTC > /etc/timezone     && sed -Ei 's/^# deb-src /deb-src /' /etc/apt/sources.list     && apt-get update -qq     && apt-get build-dep r-base-dev -y     && apt-get install wget locales -y:
60.43 W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
60.43 W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
60.43 W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
60.43 W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.canonical.com'
60.43 W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
60.43 W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
60.44 Reading package lists...
60.45 E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
------
affyPara.dockerfile:4
--------------------
   3 |
   4 | >>> RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime \
   5 | >>>     && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone \
   6 | >>>     && sed -Ei 's/^# deb-src /deb-src /' /etc/apt/sources.list \
   7 | >>>     && apt-get update -qq \
   8 | >>>     && apt-get build-dep r-base-dev -y \
   9 | >>>     && apt-get install wget locales -y
  10 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime     && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone     && sed -Ei 's/^# deb-src /deb-src /' /etc/apt/sources.list     && apt-get update -qq     && apt-get build-dep r-base-dev -y     && apt-get install wget locales -y" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

Shouldn't the sources be added to the sources.list by the sed command? The host has internet access, so I'm sure that's not the issue. I should note I am going off of this blog post: https://chainsawriot.com/postmannheim/2023/01/30/oldestr.html.

I'd really appreciate any assistance on this issue.  My lab is needing to use affyPara for a project, and unfortunately it is isn't available for modern versions of R or BioConductor.

Answer (score 0):

The error shown suggests a network issue from within the Docker build process. It shows 'Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com', which indicates that Docker is having trouble resolving the DNS for that URI.

Here are a few steps to troubleshoot this issue:

1. If you're working behind a VPN or proxy, try to disable it temporarily and rebuild the Docker image, it could be affecting the DNS resolution.
2. Alternatively, you can add a DNS server (for example Google's `8.8.8.8`) directly in your Docker daemon settings. If you're on a Unix system, you can add this line to your `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file, creating it if it doesn't exist:

   {
   "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]
   }

Then, restart the Docker daemon:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

However, if all the networking issues are covered and it's still failing, we can try a different method of installing R 2.5.1 and Bioconductor version 2.7 using Rocker legacy image.

Firstly, try replacing the base image with `rocker/r-ubuntu:16.04`, use `FROM rocker/r-ubuntu:16.04`. It is an Ubuntu 16.04 image with r-base and r-base-devel already installed. You can verify the included packages [here](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned2/tree/master/dockerfiles/_common/20.04), and accordingly modify your Dockerfile.

Then, manually install Bioconductor version 2.7 and affyPara using an older method (instead of BiocManager):

```
# Install Bioconductor version 2.7
RUN R -e 'source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite()'

# Install affyPara from Bioconductor version 2.7
RUN R -e 'source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite("affyPara")'
```

Remember that these are just suggestions to try. Building Docker images for old software versions can be challenging due to changes in the software's dependencies and other factors over time.

Comment: Hi Volodymyr, thank you for you answer. It helped me get a bit further. For some further context, the setup is a bit odd. It's a windows host, running wsl2 with Ubuntu. The network issues persist even with an added dns server on wsl, but seem to go away when I try this within a dedicated (non-wsl) VM. Thus, I have been continuing to try and compile all the needed packages in this context from source after doing the same for R 2.5.1.  BiocLite doesn't seem to work in this set up either.

Comment: One issue is that it seems rocker doesn't have an image for R 2.5.1 and ubuntu, preventing me from using Bioconductor 2.7 with this approach.  I'm now running into a specific make issue with a dependency I need, but I'll make a separate topic for that.